# Where is the best place to Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin* and SqlServerProviderSnapin*?

Tags: powershell

I created some psm1 files and I put the following lines at the top of every psm1 file,

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin*
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin*
```

However, it got warning of

```
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'mymodule' include unapproved verbs that might make them
 less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose
parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
```

And it got the following error if import the modules multiple times.

```
Add-PSSnapin : An item with the same key has already been added.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin*
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-PSSnapin], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

Add-PSSnapin : An item with the same key has already been added.
At line:2 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin*
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-PSSnapin], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Or is there a way make these snapins loaded for every users when the system is booted?

Answer (score 1):

The warning simply says that authors of `SqlServerCmdletSnapin` and `SqlServerProviderSnapin` used some 'unapproved' names for their functions. But these functions will work just fine, though MS thinks they can be 'less discoverable' (when user search commands like writing "Get-" and pressing Tab-Tab-Tab... from PS console).

So you are right to put them on the top, just add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to get rid of the warning:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

As for loading these snapins for every user, there are several options to do that using profiles. Read [Understanding the Six PowerShell Profiles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx) article.